# How to pass supervisor an environment variable from the docker run command

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, supervisord

I'm trying to pass supervisor a varibale from the docker run command so it can execute a script with the variable value. We need to set this at runtime so that each developer can have their own queue in rabbitmq so we don't clobber each others queues during testing.

Docker run command:

```
  docker run -i -p 5672:5672 -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -p 9001:9001 -p 15672:15672 -e "PARENT_HOSTNAME=MACHINED58" --rm --name shovel  -t dtwill/blkmesa:shovel
```

docker CMD statement (after looking at the docs I know why the error is happening can't provide an arbritrary parm http://supervisord.org/running.html) :

```
  CMD /usr/bin/supervisord
```

supervisor config:

```
  [program:update_rabbit_config]
  command=/src/update_rabbit_config.sh
  redirect_stderr=true
  priority=200
  startsecs=3
```

script supervisor runs:

```
  machineName=$PARENT_HOSTNAME
  echo machine name = $machineName
  sed -i .bak "s/|machine|/'$machineName'/" /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

This is the error:

```
 INFO exited: update_rabbit_config (exit status 1; not expected)
```

...so if anyone knows how to accomplish this I'd be really grateful and will do a happy dance when I'm enlightened.

Thanks!

[Updated] I updated the relevant pieces to use the recommendations in the answer. Also I'm including the result of the script when I ran it manually (after using nsenter to connect to running container):

```
  root@1e2aeaa3dfb8:/src# bash update_rabbit_config.sh 
  machine name =
  sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'
```

Looks like the environment variable isn't in the context.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a specialist for supervisor but in the [documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings) it is said that:

> Note that the subprocess will inherit the environment variables of the shell used to start “supervisord” except for the ones overridden here (`environment`). See [Subprocess Environment](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment).

From my understanding you should remove `environment=PARENT_HOSTNAME=%(PARENT_HOSTNAME)s` from the supervisor config.

---

There is also an issue with your `sed` command. Because you used single quotes `'` variable substitution won't happen. Try instead:

```
echo machine name = $PARENT_HOSTNAME
sed -i .bak "s/|machine|/$PARENT_HOSTNAME/" /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

Comment: Yes, the -e in docker run sets environment variables.  Just use 'em.

Comment: Thanks @Thomasleveil. I tried that but I'm still getting the error when that subprocess runs.

Comment: Have you removed `$PARENT_HOSTNAME` from `CMD /usr/bin/supervisord $PARENT_HOSTNAME`? You need to do this since the PARENT_HOSTNAME will be read from the environment variable, not from a supervisord parameter.

Comment: +Thomasleveil Yes sir. It looks like the code above. I removed it from the docker file and the supervisor config.